# Are recommendations for books or tools off topic?

Tags: discussion

I suggested that someone check the “How to ask” section.

While I was there, I browsed some other topics, and I found the section [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Please explain to me why *software tools commonly used by programmers* are on topic, but *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* is off-topic.

On Stack Overflow, if I am asking about a software tool commonly used, what is off topic?

Comment: We can help you **use** software tools, we won't **recommend** you one.

Comment: How do you have close to 6000 reputation and have not yet encountered the recommendation close reason and its uses? It's most commonly encountered in the case of people asking non-questions like "I want to do X in language Y, what library should I use" - those are more polls than questions and thus are off topic.

Comment: @l4mpi Maybe because of my english.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> So if I go to stackoverflow, that is on topic, if I am asking a software tool commonly use, what is off topic?

You can ask about usage, issues and general problems with the tool.

What you cannot ask is for tool recommendations.

So - "I am using [software tool commonly used by programmers] - how do I do X there?" is fine.

But - "What tool can I use for X?" is not.

Comment: Ok, I think this post was my mistake, I did not think.. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @lolka_bolka Asking such questions is not a mistake at all! It is for everyones best interest that everyone asks these questions, so StackOverflow will be a better place in general.

Comment: @KevinVoorn Not doing even rudimentary research before asking a question and asking about a topic that is discussed in detail in the help center, FAQ, and elsewhere all around meta is though.  Going straight to the "ask a question" step without searching first is in fact a mistake.

Comment: @Servy Agreed, however I never said otherwise: I haven't seen this question being discussed in several places already, that's the reason I said `such questions` :)

Comment: @KevinVoorn The fact that tool recommendations aren't allowed is discussed *all over the place*.  This is most certainly not the first time it has come up.

Comment: @Servy True, but the difference between recommendations for books/apps/... and explaining how to work with X software hasn't been discussed that often, as I cannot find anything which is the same (however a lot of similar discussions arise).

Comment: @KevinVoorn It's discussed **right in the help center**.  It has in fact been discussed quite a lot.  It's asked at least every few weeks, which is why its merited such emphasis right in the help center and FAQs.